# Symfony2 project on a distant server problems

Tags: php, symfony

I'm now looking about 2 weeks for running a website (very simple, just for testing the first steps like a HelloWorld) on a hosting, but still nothing.

I'm new on symfony and it could be that my error is "normal" but I cannot find my answer on the internet. So my problem is the following:

I developed a website on my PC with symfony2. It has just a little html/css page which I would like to see on the server. Locally, everything works fine: no errors, nothing. When I upload the entire project (after clearing cache) via FTP on the hosting (http://www.nexlink.ch/) I've got the following error:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

and the logger tells me the following things:

```
INFO - Matched route "HelloTheWorld" (parameters: "_controller": "fcbgNewsBundle:news:index", "name": "bolet", "_route": "HelloTheWorld")

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find controller "fcbgNewsBundle:news" - class "fcbg\newsBundle\Controller\newsController" does not exist." at /mnt/sites/fc-beroche.ch/web/fusio/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2333 
Context: {"exception":"Object(InvalidArgumentException)"}
```

What did I do wrong?

Here my controller:

```
<?php

namespace fcbg\newsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class newsController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction($name)
  {
    echo $name;
    $page = $this->render(
            'base.html.twig', 
            array(
                'content' => 'fcbgNewsBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                'titrePage' => $name,
                'navigation' => array(
                    array(
                        'href' => 'http://www.youpi.com', 
                        'titre' => 'menu1'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'href' => 'http://www.youpi.com', 
                        'titre' => 'menu2'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'href' => 'http://www.youpi.com', 
                        'titre' => 'menu3'
                    ),
                ),
                'css' => 'fcbgNewsBundle:Default:basicStyle.css'
            )
    );
    return $page;
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing controller file or bad class name. Expected `namespace fcbg\newsBundle\Controller;` and declaration `class newsController extends Controller { ... }`. Don't forget to inject class `Controller` via `use`. More in doc - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html

Comment: Okay thank you for your response. But in my file I exacly have what you expected (

namespace fcbg\newsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class newsController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction($name)
  {
...

) I dont know what you mean exacly by "_Don't forget to inject class Controller via use_"? thanks a lot

Comment: You used it already here: `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`

Comment: See my answer, I probably found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
INFO - Matched route "HelloTheWorld" (parameters: "_controller": "fcbgNewsBundle:news:index", "name": "bolet", "_route": "HelloTheWorld")
```

As you can see this:

```
fcbgNewsBundle:news:index
```

It is expected as

```
fcbg\NewsBundle\newsController -> indexAction
```

But you have:

```
namespace fcbg\newsBundle\Controller;
               ^
```

`n` character with **lover-case**. Use **upper-case** and you should also use upper-cased characters at the start of your controller names (`NewsController` instead of `newsController`) to avoid these problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It woks now! I searched the bug on everything but i didn't see this detail. Very helpful! I think that in this case, my website worked locally on my machine because wamp is not case sensitive but the distant webserver is! :) have a nice day!

Comment: I'm encountering this error, but checked exactly what you recommended -- the casing on my code is fine. Do you have any other suggestions where I should check? I understand you're taking a shot in the dark without seeing code/my project. My app works perfectly on localhost. The issue occurs when I'm performing a GET/POST that interacts with a bundle controller.